# Alternative to NSXMLDocument on the iPhone for XSLT purposes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xslt

I know it's been asked before ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462440/version-of-xslt-in-iphone)), but is there way to natively use XSLT on the iPhone? If not, and I need to use [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/), is there any documentation/tutorial of how to use it on the iPhone?

**EDIT:**
I've decided to use [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/). What files are necessary to include? I haven't found any tutorials of examples of use on the iPhone, and I'm unsure of how to approach it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how you want to use XSLT; not sure what you mean by "natively".  If you're just embedding a browser, MobileSafari will interpret XSLT for you.

If you're just converting one XML document into another for processing, libxslt is not a bad choice.  There's no difference using libxslt on the iPhone from any other platform.  Given Apple doesn't include headers for it, it is likely they don't want you using the bundled copy.  You are better off compiling a copy into your application instead, against the provided libxml2 library.

If you want a more specific answer you may wish to pose a more specific question. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll use libxslt then.

Answer (score 4):

Cannot use libXSLT on iPhone. Not as of today. App will be rejected. libXSLT is built into the iOS andd COULD be called - but this is a private API of the iPhone and will cause rejection. If you compile the libxslt library yourself and statically link it to your app, you will still get rejected. Many people have reported this bug in the app review process but nothing has yet changed.

Comment: I agree Rudolf. It means no inApp XSLT, but you COULD consider implementing XSLT via webservice or similar. That would externalize it. However, my comment was related to an earlier version of iOS (probably 5). I haven't attempted this in the most recent releases after having wasted collosal amounts of time on it.

Comment: I will transform the XML in Swift (using NSXMLParser) instead. Don't feel like wasting collosal amounts of time. :)