# Generating HTML programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In C#, I use XML/XSLT transformation to isolate markup from data. What's the equivalent in Objective C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XML/XSLT isn't something that is specific to C#, and XSLT can be used with objective c.

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712658/alternative-to-nsxmldocument-on-the-iphone-for-xslt-purposes).