# How to use XSLT in iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, xslt

I am new to iPad programming. Can anybody tell me how to convert xml file to html file using xslt in iPad . I have read other posts related to this question but i am not able to get the proper answer. Do i have to use any library for it, how to import these file to my objective c code and how to process it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question it has a similar discussion which might help you to explore more,

[Alternative to NSXMLDocument on the iPhone for XSLT purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712658/alternative-to-nsxmldocument-on-the-iphone-for-xslt-purposes)

Krio

This link is worth exploring too!

http://ditchnet.org/aquaxsl/

Comment: Thank you, it was great help for me.