# Building libxslt for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, libxslt

I just had an app rejected for linking to `libxslt` using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462440/version-of-xslt-in-iphone/2273697#2273697).

I'd really like to use XSLT in my app, so it looks like my only shot is to compile it myself.  I don't want to use a `UIWebView` because I want to store the resulting HTML, not just display it.

Has anyone done this -- compiled `libxslt` for the iPhone?

After some Googling, I've got an old Xcode solution from [here](http://www.explain.com.au/oss/libxml2xslt.html) and  git-cloned the latest `libxslt` from [gnome.org](http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html).  Neither approach has worked out so far (autoconf bails out, and the Xcode project is missing a bunch of files).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update 7/21**

I found a workaround by giving `UIWebView` some XML linked to an XSL stylesheet.  After the data loads, 
I can grab the transformed HTML like this ([source](http://lists.apple.com/archives/safari-iphone-web-dev/2008/Sep/msg00001.html)):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"];
}
```

That said, if anyone has any hints on using `libxslt` directly, I'd love to hear them.  Dropping into javascript seems so...unsavory.

Comment: Hey did you find the solution to the problem?because i am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to add dylibs, but you can link to a .a file.  Can you get the configure for libxslt to output a .a file instead?

Comment: Well, that's kind of the problem...  I can't even get ./configure to work on the source I downloaded.