# Applying XSLT to an XML coming from a Webservice in iOS

Tags: xml, ios, xslt, uiwebview

In my iPAD application, I get an XML from a webservice.I use NSURL connection to call the Webservice and get Data from it. I usually parse the XML using NSXMLParser and display the data on a UITableView.

But due to a requirement I need to get the XML and apply and XSLT on it and display it on a UIWebView.
I know the basics of applying an XSLT to an XML and displaying it. However, how would I do it dynamically in my code?

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/downloads.html) - see here for more info - [Version of XSLT in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462440/version-of-xslt-in-iphone/4123575#4123575)