# xpaths and xml iteration

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xpath

I have an xml like this:

```
    <root>
   ...
    <images xmlns:a="http://.../Arrays">
        <a:string>http://images...233/Detail.jpg</a:string>
        <a:string>http://images....233/Detail2.jpg</a:string>
    </images>
   ...
   <images xmlns:a="http://.../Arrays">
        <a:string>http://images...233/Detail3.jpg</a:string>
        <a:string>http://images....233/Detail4.jpg</a:string>
        <a:string>http://images....233/Detail5.jpg</a:string>
    </images>
....
<images xmlns:a="http://.../Arrays">
        <a:string>http://images...233/Detail6.jpg</a:string>
        <a:string>http://images....233/Detail7.jpg</a:string>
    </images>
   ....
<root>
```

How can i iterate to put all my images in NSArray ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i iterate to put all my images in NSArray ?

**I don't know what you mean by `NSArray`.**

Usually an XPath engine exposes a method like `SelectNodes(string XpathExpression)`, possibly with overloads for a `NamespaceManager` object - argument.

And this method typically returns an `XmlNodelist` object, which contains all results and allows to iterate over them.

**One XPath expression that selects all the text nodes that contain images in the provided XML document**:

```
<images xmlns:a="http://.../Arrays">
    <a:string>http://images...233/Detail.jpg</a:string>
    <a:string>http://images....233/Detail2.jpg</a:string>
</images>
```

**is**:

```
/*/*/text()
```

This selects any text node whose parent is a child of the top element in the XML document -- in this case such nodes are exactly the two text nodes with string value, respectively:

`"http://images...233/Detail.jpg"`

and

`"http://images....233/Detail2.jpg"` .

Comment: `NSArray` is the standard array/list class in Apple's Cocoa and Cocoa Touch frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this on an iOS device, you would preferably use a third-party C library that implements XPath evaluation for you, as the built-in XML support provided for iOS does not. Your best bet is using libxslt, but because the downloadable version of libxslt come in the form of a dynamic library it can't be used directly on iOS. Instead, you'll want to pull down the source code for libxslt and build it directly into your app. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123575/830760) for more information on getting libxslt to work on iOS.

Once you have libxslt working in your project, you can use C code to parse the XML and evaluate arbitrary XPath expressions such as "/*/*/text()", as was suggested by @Dmitre Novatchev. There are many variants on how you can do this, but something like this gives you an example:

```
CFArrayRef findImages(CFStringRef filename) {

    xmlInitParser();
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

    // Parse XML template document into DOM tree
    CFIndex filenameLength = CFStringGetLength(filePath);
    char *fileNameCString = (char *) calloc(filenameLength + 1, sizeof(char));
    CFStringGetCString(filePath, fileNameCString, filenameLength + 1, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadFile(fileNameCString, NULL, 0);
    if (doc == NULL) 
    {
        // Error - File not readable
        free(fileNameCString);
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        free(fileNameCString);
        xmlCleanupParser();
    }

    /* Create xpath evaluation context */
    xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if(xpathCtx == NULL) 
    {
        // Error - Failed to create Xpath context
        return NULL;
    }


    /* Evaluate xpath expression */
    char *xpathCString = "/*/*/text()";
    xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST xpathCString, xpathCtx);
    if(xpathObj == NULL) 
    {
        // Error - Failed to evaluate XPath
        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx); 
        return NULL;
    }
    xmlNodeSetPtr resultNodes = xpathObj->nodesetval;


    // You'll want to double-check the following part: I don't have sample code for
    // this so I can't be certain this is 100% correct, but it gets the idea across!

    CFMutableArrayRef result = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultNodes->nodeNr; i++) {
        char *imageCString = xmlNodeGetContent(resultNodes->nodeTab[i]);
        CFStringRef imageString = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, imageCString, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        CFArrayAppendValue(result, imageString);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I've put this code sample together based on some working sample code I had for evaluating an XPath expression, but the end part where I assemble it into an array is off the top of my head: It might not work completely right!

Note that this function takes a CFString for the filename of the XML file and returns a CFArray for the result. These types are "toll-free bridged" with the Objective-C NSString and NSArray types. That means you can call them from objective-C with the "normal" types you are used to using, and they will be correctly understood in the C code I've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i am using GDataXML to parse my XML and it's working fine, but i have a trouble to iterate with this portion of my xml ?

Comment: If you have already worked with GDataXML, can you show me how you will put all the .png in NSMutableArray for example ? thanks again

Comment: I've never worked with GDataXML - But a quick google search turned up http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml, where they provide an example of evaluating an XPath expression against the document and returning the results as an NSArray